# What user interface element would I use to take and crop a photo on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'd like to be able to take a photo from the iPhone's camera, select a polygon within that photo, crop the photo to match, and then fit the resulting image to the screen.

What user interface element would you suggest for me to start doing this?

I'm a Java programmer and just getting started with the iPhone, so I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: "overly broad", I think.

Comment: This is going to be done with more than just a few snippets... I'd do some initial research on the view controllers for the camera etc first..

Comment: its not the main idea to use camera, dear barfoon, but primary is where to place iamge (e.g. from camera roll) and how to process it? tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by looking at sample code from Apple for UIImagePickerController to start getting the image. When you are comfortable with that you can start thinking about how to crop the image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Should I use something based on OpenGL or just like that next to process image?

Comment: Also if you're comfortable, would you share some book for java/as3 developer to better understand cocoa/objective-c please? :)

Comment: @Eugenev - I'd recommend looking at the getting-started resources pointed out in this question, because there's a lot out there to help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c